# Joining method from another class in java

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to understand Java by trying several things out. I'm using two classes in the same package. One is called `Box`, the other one is called `TestBox`. I want to calculate the area of the company box using `calculateArea()`. This function is in another class `TestBox`. However the function `calculateArea` in `Box` does not respond to the function in `TestBox`. I'm missing a link between these two classes. This seems like a simple problem, but I have not found the solution yet. Can someone please help me out?

```
package box;

public class Box {

    int length;
    int width;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box company = new Box();

        company.length = 3;
        company.width = 4;
        int area = company.calculateArea();
    }
}
```

```
package box;

public class TestBox {

    int length;
    int width;

    int calculateArea(){
        int area = length * width;
        System.out.println("Area= " + area);
    return area;
    }
}
```

Comment: The type (Read: Class) of "company" must have a method called "calculateArea".

Comment: If `calculateArea` belongs to `TestBox` class then you can invoke this method on instance of this class. Since `Box` doesn't have `calculateArea` method you can't invoke it on `Box` instance (held in `company` reference.

Comment: I think you're looking for `TestBox company = new TestBox();`

Comment: As others have said use TestBox instead of Box. The other option would be to move calculateArea() to Box, and just have TestBox inherit Box then both classes would be able to use that method. You'd then add additional methods to TestBox that only TestBox requires.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to clarify a bit what is your design, I mean what the classes Box and TestBox should do, moreover I advice use to use an IDE such as Eclipse or Intellij Idea helping you with syntax highlight and founding possible errors.

What you are dealing with is the [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)), that is

> packing of data and functions into a single component.

so it is feasible that the area of the box is calculated by the Box class itself.

About your code, a possible solution could be:

```
package com.foo;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box(3, 4);

        int area = box.calculateArea();

        System.out.println("Box area is: " + area);
    }
}

class Box {

    private int l;
    private int w;

    Box(int length, int width) {
        l = length;
        w = width;
    }

    int calculateArea() {
        return l * w;
    }
}
```

Another possible approach could be

```
package com.foo;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box(3, 4);

        TestBox testBox = new TestBox();

        int area = testBox.calculateArea(box);

        System.out.println("Box area is: " + area);
    }
}

class Box {

    private int l;
    private int w;

    Box(int length, int width) {
        l = length;
        w = width;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return l;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return w;
    }

}

class TestBox {
    int calculateArea(Box box) {
        return box.getLength() * box.getWidth();
    }
```

If you want to have a separate class doing the job, but it is something I do not like, the function computing the area is related to the box and works on box variables, I prefer the first one, but it should be better to have more details in case.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per the below approach, you need to make parameterized constructor where you can pass the value of length and width at the time of creating TestBox object. You also need to create a default constructor for future save in case if later you only want to create default TestBox object like new TestBox(); 
You can calculate area in you TestBox class and than return the value in the Box class. You don't need to create separate length and width variable in Box class and no need to create a object of Box.

```
package box;

public class Box {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestBox company = new TestBox (3,4);
        int area = company.calculateArea();
    }
}

package box;

public class TestBox {

    private int length;
    private int width;

    TestBox()
    {
    }

    TestBox(int l, int w)
    {
      this.length = l;
      this.width = w;
    }

    public int getLength() {
       return length;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
       return width;
    }


    int calculateArea(){
        int area = length * width;
        System.out.println("Area= " + area);
        return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestBox company = new TestBox();

    company.length = 3;
    company.width = 4;
    int area = company.calculateArea();

}

}
```

Comment: Or simply change `Box company = new Box();` to `TestBox company = new TestBox();`... BTW it would be nice to beside code solution describe what was original problem and why your solution will work.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!